# Expression for $x\notin A$, where $A=\left\{x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{a_i}{3^i}\; : \; a_i\in\{0,2\} \right\}\subseteq [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$A:=\left\{x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{a_i}{3^i}\; : \; a_i\in\{0,2\} \right\}\subseteq [0,1].$$

If $x\in [0,1]\setminus A$ it's correct to say that $$x=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{a_i}{3^i}+\frac{1}{3^n}+\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty\frac{b_i}{3^i}\tag1,$$ where $a_i\in\{0,2\}$ and the $b_i$ not all zero and not all equal to two?

I understood that if $(1)$ holds then the $b_i$ can't all be zero and all equal to two, otherwise $x $would belong to $A$, what I don't understand is why if $x$ doesn't belong to A, then it holds $(1)$ as writing for $x$.

Could someone explain the reasoning to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can expand any real number on the interval $[0,1]$ using ternary system: for example, $1/3 = 0.1000\dots$, $1/2 = 0.111\dots$, $1 = 0.222\dots$. Since we do not exclude infinite sequences of digits $2$, the expansion may be non-unique; indeed $1/3 = 0.0222\dots$.

Let $x \in [0,1]$ be any number with a ternary expansion $x = 0.d_1\dots d_{n-1} 222\dots$, where $n=1,2,\dots$,  and the digit $d_{n-1} != 2$, that is $d_{n-1} \in \{0,1\}$.  Then $x$ has an equivalent ternary expansion $x = 0.d_1\dots \hat{d}_{n-1}000\dots$, where $\hat{d}_{n-1} = d_{n-1}+1$.

Thus we have two important special cases:

- if a ternary expansion of $x$ ends with digits $1000\dots$, then this may be equivalently replaced with $0222\dots$
- if a ternary expansion of $x$ ends with digits $1222\dots$, then this may be equivalently replaced with $2000\dots$

Finally, $x\not\in A$ by definition implies that its ternary expansion cannot be written using digits $0$ and $2$ only.  This means that after some finite number of $0$ or $2$ digits (the first sum) there must be at least one $1$.  However, in accordance with the two special cases outlined above, this $1$ may not be followed by identical $0$s or $2$s, otherwise we could represent the same number using $0$ and $2$ digits only, and it would be in $A$.